# The constructor PrintWriter(BufferedWriter) is undefined

Tags: java, syntax-error

I am trying to create a report for which I am shown with a syntax error

> "The constructor PrintWriter(BufferedWriter) is undefined".

for :

```
new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(OUT_FOLDER, "emailable-test-run-report.html"))));
```

I am using JDK 1.7

Can someone please guide me through this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the import statements for PrintWriter and BufferedWriter classes?

Comment: If you post Your actual code here, will help to get an answer fast. Also when you get an `Error` or `Exception` better to provide `statckTrace` here. BTW I am not sure there is an issue in this line of code.

Comment: Can you show the entire stack trace, and maybe your imports?  `BufferedWriter` extends `Writer`, and there **IS** a constructor for `PrintWriter(Writer w)`

Comment: You can also write to the file with just: PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(OUT_FOLDER + "/emailable-test-run-report.html");

Comment: Thanks to all. It was an issue of imports as stated by @CodeChimp. Importing BufferedWriter was enough to tackle this one for me.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue - for clarity, you need the following lines at the top of your sketch:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
```